# What this in javascript? Is it bad practice?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, handler

Right now i'm following a tutorial, and the guy who does the tutorial does this

```
let ball = ballObject = new AmmobtTransform();
```

inside a function to make "ball" a local variable, and "ballObject" a global variable at the same time. Now, he calls the "= ballObject" bit a 'handler', but I cant seem to find documentation of that (i find JavaScript event handlers e.g touchdown events instead) so what is this, and is it an old/new feature? A link to documentation  would be fine. Thank you.

Comment: This is a bad way of doing things imo, if you already had a global variable then you wouldn't need a local one, and implicitly creating one is also not good and usually a bug, and correctly fails when enabling strict mode.

Comment: I don't see any handler here either. I'm getting doubts about the quality of this tutorial, is it publicly available on the Internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a chained assignment. An assignment expression (`a = b`) has a result, which is the value that was assigned. So by doing `let ball = ballObject = new AmmobtTransform();` the author is doing (effectively¹) this:

```js
ballObject = new AmmobtTransform();
let ball = ballObject;
```

It's something that's reasonable to do in some situations. Like anything, it can also be misused. **But:**

> ...to make "ball" a local variable, and "ballObject" a global variable at the same time...

If you mean that `ballObject` is not declared anywhere, and the author is using that statement to create a *new* global variable, rather than just assigning to a variable that is already declared in some containing scope, that is definitely poor practice. It relies on what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). In general, use strict mode so that doing that is the error it always should have been. :-)

> ...he calls the "= ballObject" bit a 'handler'...

That seems odd. The constructor name `AmmobtTransform` doens't immediately suggest to me that it's any kind of "handler," and if it were, it wouldn't just apply to `ballObject`, but to `ball` as well.

To sum up:

1. It's a chained assignment (`a = b = c`)
2. Chained assignments are occasionally appropriate
3. Relying on The Horror of Implicit Globals is never appropriate; use strict mode to avoid doing it by accident
4. Calling `ballobject` a "handler" seems odd

---

¹ Okay, so it's really a bit more like:

```js
let ball;
const tmp =  new AmmobtTransform();
ballObject = tmp;
ball = tmp;
```

...(with `tmp` under the covers and gone by the end of it) but that's just pedantry on my part. ;-)

Comment: Wow, even better answer that I expected! tyvm